# create table from the post data array in php

Tags: php, arrays, post

I need help here in my practice program. I  have a json array:

```
myData=[{"plank_number":"1","thickness":"5","width":"7","length_t":"8","quantity":"1"},
 {"plank_number":"2","thickness":"5","width":"6","length_t":"7","quantity":"1"},
 {"plank_number":"3","thickness":"6","width":"7","length_t":"8","quantity":"1"},
 .........................(could be more)]
```

this array is generated everytime you add plank in my grid (jqgrid). I also have here a php file with some html tag. What I am confused about is how will I code my .php program so that it will accept my variable `myData` and create another table in from it.

**EDIT**

My questions are: How to POST a JSON array to an other page? and,

How to output the JSON array in an html table?
I have a submit button in here in my html file. And my variable `myData` is from my javascript file. Thanks

Comment: So do I get it right: You have the JSON-array $myData and now you want to POST this array to another .php which does something with the array?

Comment: yes....that's what i am trying to do right now.

Comment: So Question #1 is: How to POST a JSON array to an other page, and question #2 is: How to output the JSON array in an html table - right? If so, feel free to edit your post and make that more clear ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use json_decode to convert the post data into a php associative array then you can loop through it and generate the table.
Something along the lines of....

```
<?PHP
$data = json_decode($_POST['myData'], true); // convert into a php array
$numrows = count($data); // count the number of rows you need

// generate the table
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>plank number</td><td>thickness</td><td>width</td></tr>"; // your headings
for($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[$i]['plank_number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[$i]['thickness'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[$i]['width'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your problem, but what about using "[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php)" PHP function ?

Comment: how would Im going to do that? I am thinking of breaking my array into this `mydata[0]={"plank_number":"1","thickness":"5","width":"7","length_t":"8","quantity":"1"}; mydata[1] = {"plank_number":"1","thickness":"5","width":"7","length_t":"8","quantity":"1"}.....` but i just dont know how. And I dont know how to declare `myData` in php as an array